# Spring 5 Scheduler using in mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-scheduled

I'm using spring 5 scheduler in my web app & I need to set my fixedrate at run time, so I'm using ServletContextListener with `@WebListener` annoated. In servletcontext class I'm using `TaskScheduler scheduler.setFixedAtRate(<Runnable>, <Get value from DB>, <time period>);`
I had annotated my service class
Scheduler configured successfully & executing on time.
But problem is getting `@Autowired` my services in scheduled class, they are not binding. While other business logic `@Autowired` working successfully.

Comment: can you use the `@Scheduled` annotation? (http://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks)

Comment: No I can't because request is that to add fixedrate at run time. I got the answer from some googling, problem is that I'm using ServletContextLisnter, so contextlistener loaded before application start, that's why my scheduled class @Autowired is not working properly.
ochi: do you have any other idea besides ServletContextListener? Because I need to scheduled at run time but after application deployed or loaded. Is there better approach for this in spring or JEE???

Comment: I am sorry I am not understanding, the fixed rate is to be set at runtime or at startup/load time?

Comment: If it is at load time, you can do something like `@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${fixedRate.in.milliseconds}")` where the value comes from your properties file

Comment: ok let me elaborate you. I have my milliseconds value in database table, so I need to scheduler on fixedrate of value exists in database table, that's why I need to implement a class which one scheduled after application startup. Now you got my point?

Comment: Ochi I got an answer from some googling, I can use @EventListener for this, but little confused about classes scheduled after application startup or it will execute during applicationcontext loading. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Posible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440826/setting-value-for-config-of-spring-scheduled-from-database

Comment: Ochi not working for me this sample.

Answer (score 0):

It's because ServlerContextListener mostly isn't managed by Spring. It's well explained in here: 
[Spring @Autowired annotation doesn't work in Java TimerTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39060805/spring-autowired-annotation-doesnt-work-in-java-timertask?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Ok then Mafuj what sould I use for this?